# Hyperplane separation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $K\subset X$ a nonempty, closed and convex subset. Show that $$K=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\leq \sup\limits_{y\in K}\phi(y)\quad\forall\phi\in X'\}$$ Here $X'$ is the dual space to $X$.

My idea so far, was to use the separation theorem for convex sets: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem

Suppose

- $\exists x_0\in X\backslash K$ where  $X\backslash K$ is open so there $\exists\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x_0)\subset X\backslash K$ and $B_\epsilon(x_0)\cap K=\emptyset$
- $\exists\phi\in X',\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(x)\leq\alpha\leq\phi(y)\quad \forall x\in K,y\in B_\epsilon(x_0)$

Now I'm lost ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but I would recommend using the other version of the hyperplane separation theorem.

Suppose $x_0\notin K$.  Then the set $\{x_0\}$ is compact, convex, and disjoint from $K$.  Thus, the [Hahn-Banach separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem) (the second bullet point) furnishes some $\phi\in X'$, $s,t\in\mathbb R$ such that 
$$ \phi(y)<s<t<\phi(x_0) $$
for all $y\in K$.  Taking the supremum over $y\in K$, we obtain
$$ \sup\limits_{y\in K}\phi(y)<\phi(x_0), $$
and thus $x_0\notin\{x\in X:\phi(x)\leq \sup\limits_{y\in K}\phi(y)\quad\forall\phi\in X'\}. $  In other words, $\{x\in X:\phi(x)\leq \sup\limits_{y\in K}\phi(y)\quad\forall\phi\in X'\}\subset K$.

I'm sure you can (or already have) handled the other inclusion.

Comment: very comprehensive answer, thank you. For  $\supset K$: K is closed and convex and therefore always a true subset of $K=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\leq \sup\limits_{y\in K}\phi(y)\quad\forall\phi\in X'\}$, but there is probably a cleaner way to express this?

Comment: @JonathanKrill That's basically what I had in mind.  Closedness and convexity aren't required though, given any subset $C\subset X$, any $x\in C$, and any $\phi\in X'$ we have $\phi(x)\leq\sup\limits_{y\in C}\phi(y)$.